# special HTML elements within a textarea

Tags: html, css

I have a system where I want users to be able to customise an order confirmation email.  The email has placeholders which are replaced with real customer data.

At the moment we tell people to use tags like {customer_name}, however this confuses some people and has a lot of room for error.

I would like to have something where the placeholder can be inserted from a menu and then acts as a unit, just like any character in a textarea.

I have thought about using tinyMCE and writing a plugin but this seems like overkill.

Does anybody have any ideas, or know of any tools I could use?

Thank you.

Comment: It's called "markdown" and is used here and extensively in Wiki.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461981/simple-jquery-bbcode-example

Comment: to me the title seems to be a little bit confusing... do you want to insert "HTML elements" or like Diodeus said "markdowns"? HTML elements would be <a>,<p>,<div>,... whereas {customer_name} would be a markdown. What do you want those elements to be used for?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really style items within a text area. I think the best you could do is have a menu that inserts the tags that you are already using.

Another thing you could do is add a 'preview' div below the textarea. It would live parse the users entry (or just do it when the user pushes a 'preview' button) and you could do replacements on the tags to insert an image or something that made more sense to the user than the shortcode.

Comment: Where did you read that he's trying to style items in a textarea?

Comment: I didn't, I read that he wanted a placeholder that was inserted as a unit. I read that to mean that he wanted the 'unit' to be something other than text.